# Машинный максимум double на С++

Tags: c++, double

Всем доброго вечера. У меня есть задача - определить максимально возможное значение, которое может храниться в типе double, но использовать библиотеку limits при решении нельзя. Решаю задачу с помощью возведения двойки в степень, при котором значение выходит за пределы типа. Нагляднее покажу в коде:

```
    double infmax_d = 2.0;
    double almostinf_d = 1.0, infinity_d = 1.0;
    int counter_max_d = 0, counter_notmax_d = -1;

    while (infmax_d > almostinf_d) {
        almostinf_d = infmax_d;
        infmax_d = infmax_d * 2.0;
        counter_max_d++;
        counter_notmax_d++;

    }

    //cout << counter_notmax_d << endl;

    for (int t = 0; t < counter_notmax_d; t++) {
        infinity_d = infinity_d * 2.0;
    }

    cout << "Max value for double type: " << infinity_d << endl;
```

Вывод программы в данном случае:

> Max value for double type: 8.98847e+307

Это значение в два раза меньше истинного. При умножении на два сразу происходит вывод inf. Если отнять от infinity_d 0.5 и умножить на 2, результат тот же. Но если отнимать 5e300, то получается найти ближайшее к нужному число.
Как можно модифицировать код, чтобы добиться нужного результата?

Comment: >У меня есть задача - определить максимально возможное значение, которое может храниться в типе double, но использовать библиотеку limits при решении нельзя

Единственный корректный способ это сделать, соответствующий Стандарту языка - это использовать эту самую библиотеку. Все прочие гениальные идеи и постановки задачи нуждаются в очень-очень-очень железобетонном обосновании. "Мне препод такую задачу поставил" - не является обоснованием, так как вызывает вопросы уже к преподу.

Comment: Смотрите описание формата [double](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8). Заполняете память, занимаемое такой переменной битиками. Печатаете ее

Answer (score 1):

Как уже заметил [@gbg в комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1332385/%d0%9c%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bc-double-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%a1/1332562#comment2356641_1332385), в соответствии со стандартом, единственный корректный способ узнать максимально возможное значение - причем не только типа `double`, но и любого арифметического типа - использовать ту самую библиотеку.

Можете открыть последний черновик [N4868](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4868.pdf) последнего стандарта и найти там в § 6.8.2 описания для всех арифметических типов. В частности, в пункте 12 сообщается о числах с плавающей точкой.

> 12. ... The value representation of floating-point types is
>     **implementation-defined**. ... Specializations of the standard library
>     template **std::numeric_limits shall specify** the maximum and minimum
>     values of each arithmetic type for an implementation.

Если Вы хотите подробнее узнать, как устроены числа с плавающей точкой изнутри, то ссылку Вам дал [@avp в комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1332385/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BC-double-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%A1/1332562#comment2356643_1332385). Если очень коротко, то число с плавающей точкой двойной точности может быть представлено 64 битами, при этом

- 0 бит  =  знак числа
- 1 - 11 биты  =  смещенный порядок
- 12 - 63 биты  =  абсолютная часть мантиссы

Я воспользовался библиотекой `limits`, чтобы получить максимальное `double` , а затем посмотрел, как оно представлено в памяти.

```
double d = numeric_limits<double>::max( );    // 1.79769e+308

//    0   11111111110   11...11               // представление в памяти  
//    ^   ^         ^   ^     ^ 
//    0   1        11   12   63
```

Со знаковым битом все понятно, если бы там была единица, мы бы получили отрицательное число. Но, как видите, и 11ый бит тоже выставлен в 0. Значит, прямолинейное выставление всех битов в единички не сработает. Если Вы все же попробуете, то вывод, скорее всего, окажется `nan` то есть "not a number".

Поэтому, когда преподаватель скажет Вам правильный способ, вернитесь, пожалуйста, сюда и явите это решение свету. Очень любопытно его *очень-очень-очень железобетонное обоснование*

Comment: Как раз все биты характеристики, выставленные в единицу, согласно спецификации и определяют "не число" (NaN), либо бесконечность (INF). Бесконечность, кстати, равна 0x7FF0000000000000, т.е. 0 111111111111 00..00